# Tag Manager - Enhanced ecommerce

Tags: google-tag-manager, enhanced-ecommerce

I am trying to set up **Enhanced E-commerce** tracking for a hotel booking site. The site uses a third party for booking and taking payments.

The booking site have implemented the **data layer**.

But the data is **not getting** transferred to **Google Analytics.**

This is what I have done so far. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

1. Added a universal analytics tag.

[image: UA tag]

2. Added a custom event trigger with the name supplied by booking site
3. Created a variable with data layer and Enhanced E-commerce enabled.

[image: enhanced ecommerce variable]